# rails - Adding static html pages without controller support

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4, static-pages

I have a problem.

Well, I've got an website with some sitemap and I want to keep active links to several html pages due to their high ranking in Google. Sample page has the address: http://domain.com/my_important_page.html - this is a static page in pure html written (requires no backend support).

Webpage has been re-written in RunyOnRails. How to make routes.rb to the above page(s) (ex. domain.com/my_important_page.html) was seen at the same web address as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drop `my_important_page.html` in the `public` directory.

Comment: didn't work for me. somehow, my routes interpreted the second parameter of link_for as the action and inferred the controller was the one hosting the page with the link. This was problematic as I need to "escape the controller" here.